# Align all item to left except last in a flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Following is my code in which I am trying to align the last div `(class="four")` to the right and I am using `align-self: flex-end;` but still its not going to the right. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: yellow;
}

.three {
  background: pink;
}

.four {
  background: teal;
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`margin-left:auto;` will do the job.

> One use of [auto margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) in the main axis is to separate flex items
>   into distinct "groups"...

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: yellow;
}

.three {
  background: pink;
}

.four {
  background: teal;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but any specific reason why we need to add `margin-left:auto;` in this case ? Let me know if I am missing something here conceptually.

Comment: I have mentioned the link, you can read there more about it.

Answer (score 3):

use `margin-left: auto`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: yellow;
}

.three {
  background: pink;
}

.four {
  background: teal;
  display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but any specific reason why we need to add margin-left:auto; in this case ? Let me know if I am missing something here conceptually.

Answer (score 1):

Align self property is used to adjust the flex items on the cross axis.

Please try this code.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: yellow;
}

.three {
  background: pink;
}

.four {
  background: teal;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: yellow;
}

.three {
  background: pink;
}

.four {
  background: teal; 
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```